# How convert Date variable format in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have bash variable named `date_export` that have `2021-09-22` as a value.
I want assign it to other bash variable named `DATE_EXPORT` but having other format `20210922`
I tried :

```
DATE_EXPORT=$(date -d ${date_export} + '%Y%m%d')
```

But, it does not work, any help, please

Comment: `date -d "$date_export" '+%Y%m%d'` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output format is a single word starting with `+`, not two separate arguments `+` and the format.

```
DATE_EXPORT=$(date -d "$date_export" +"%Y%m%d")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date_export=2021-09-22
DATE_EXPORT=${date_export//-/}
echo $DATE_EXPORT # prints 20210922
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the dashes using POSIX-shell grammar:

```sh
DATE_EXPORT=$(IFS=-; printf %s $date_export)
```

Or without spawning a sub-shell:

```sh
DATE_EXPORT=${date_export%-*}
DATE_EXPORT=${DATE_EXPORT%-*}${DATE_EXPORT#*-}${date_export##*-}
```